# SP2010 VS2010 Sequential Workflow not able to create a Task in Tasks List With Custom content type

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio

I have created the sequential workflow for three level approval workflow with while condition. I am starting the workflow manually using SOM since I need to update one of the fields later inserting data into it.

It's creating task but deleting immediately and showing status as `error occurred in workflow attached list`. Nowhere I am not getting info about that except sometimes the following error code occurs: `-2130575205`, now this exception also not showing.

Comment: check the ULS logs for errors? My assumption that It could be that you workflow is either trying to access a deleted item or something that has not been created yet!